# Resolve $ref by relative file path

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsonschema, ajv

I want to split json-schemas into multiple local files, and make referring to them as easy and straight-forward as possible. For this, my first intuition was `$ref` to a path relative to the current file.

However, the json-schema way doesn't seem to have a standard case for this, as `$ref` is resolved relative to `$id`, and the "current file's path" isn't available. `$id` sadly [mixes two purposes](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#the-id-property) (why does it do this?):

- unique identifier
- base URI for `$ref`

I thought of this workaround, dragging the local path along, by injecting it into the `$id`, but this obviously destroys the other purpose of `$id`:

```
import Ajv from 'ajv';
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';

const load = async (uri: string) => {
  const schema = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(uri, 'utf8'));
  schema.$id = uri; // do the deed
  return schema;
};

const ajv = new Ajv({ loadSchema: load });

(async () => {
  const startSchema = await load('some/path/example.json');
  const validate = await ajv.compileAsync(startSchema);
})();
```

Luckily, in my case, i really don't care about `$id` otherwise, but isn't there a standard way for this? I can't imagine it's that abnormal of a use-case.

---

Example structure, because it was requested:

Local folder structure example:

```
 schemas
├─  sub
│  └─ start.schema.json
└─ referenced.schema.json
```

- start.schema.json:

  ```
   {
     "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
     "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/id1",
     "type": "object",
     "properties": {
        "bad": { "$ref": "../referenced.schema.json" }
     }
   }
  ```
- referenced.schema.json

  ```
   {
     "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
     "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/id2",
     "type": "integer"
   }
  ```

Resolved will be relative to `$id`, if i don't replace it: `https://example.com/referenced.schema.json`, which is completely wrong.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Why can't you use relative paths in `$ref` to reference your other files? Can you include a sample schema file to show how you are using `$id` and `$ref`?

Comment: @Ether added example structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Use `file://` for all your `$id`s**

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "file:///path/to/schemas/id1",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "bad": { "$ref": "../referenced.schema.json" }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "file:///path/to/schemas/id2",
  "type": "integer"
}
```

**Option 2: Pre-load all your schemas**

```js
import Ajv from 'ajv';
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';

const load = async (uri: string) => {
  return JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(uri, 'utf8'));
};

const ajv = new Ajv();

(async () => {
  ajv.addSchema(await load('schemas/sub/start.schema.json'));
  ajv.addSchema(await load('schemas/referenced.schema.json'));
  const validate = ajv.getSchema("https://example.com/schemas/id1");
})();
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with the first option is, that hard-coding absolute paths is non-portable. E.g. pulling the resources from git, or just moving a folder, invalidates everything. I'd have hoped, that it was possible to have a relative path for a `$ref`, and have the schemas be self-contained. The second option means having file paths in an additional resource, be that as shown in code, or in another data file. It might be an option, to require all schemas to be inside a folder, and just pre-load everything e.g. via a glob `schemas/**/*.schema.{json,yaml}`, but it might load unnecessary ones.

Comment: For the glob approach: As schema `$id` is always on the top level, i could parse all schemas once (not load them in `ajv` yet), look at their `$id`, remember a table `$id`->path, and then dynamically load from a flat structure, where each schema is referenced just by name.

Comment: Remember, you only need to load schemas once. You can do it at app boot and then the schemas are there and ready to be referenced whenever you need them. Also, loading schemas is relatively cheap. It doesn't compile schemas until you call `getSchema` and even then it only compiles the schemas it needs for that validator.

Comment: Also, if you want to try another implementation, Hyperjump JSV (https://github.com/hyperjump-io/json-schema-validator) allows you to load a schema from a file path and that location is used as the identifier of the schema if there is no `$id`. That would give you the portability you want without having to pre-load schemas. I don't think you can do that with ajv, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the alternative. I am making a small tool, that generates standalone validation code modules, along with typescript declarations, for json-schema/jtd, which i can then use elsewhere. `ajv-cli` doesn't have all features i need, sadly. It's mostly just wiring together some packages, which do the heavy lifting (`ajv` doing most work). I think the presented solutions for loading the schemas are both good enough, and as-good-as-it-gets. Thanks again :)